# Is there error raised from api when creating deployment without enough resources?

Tags: kubernetes

I am usingkubernetes-client/python to create a deployment. When space is insufficient the create api will just hold there and waiting for more resources. I need to check from k8s admin GUI to root the issue. Is it possible to raise error when resources not enough, instead of just stuck there?

Comment: It's surprising that the call would block. It should succeed or fail with an error per the docs for [`created_namespace_deployment`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/AppsV1Api.md#create_namespaced_deployment). You say "space is insufficient". The Deployment's creation should result in a ReplicaSet's creation which should result in Pod creation but these are independent events. Your question lacks code and details of the issue you observe and so it's difficult to help.

Comment: The ReplicaSet could fail to create Pods if a ResourceQuota is exceeded too; but again, the Deployment won't visibly fail and your client code should proceed (unless you're explicitly waiting for it to be ready).  If more resources get added to the cluster, for example via the cluster autoscaler, the Deployment/ReplicaSet should proceed on its own.